# RxJS6: reset stream after completion

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I've been playing around a bit with **RxJS 6**. I am trying to implement `dragstart, dragmove and dragend`. This is the code I have so far.

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/concatMap';
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/takeUntil';
import { repeat } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/repeat';
import { first } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/first';

const mousedown = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'mousedown');
const mousemove = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'mousemove');
const mouseup = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'mouseup');

const dragstart = mousedown.pipe(
  first()
);

const dragmove = mousedown.pipe(
  concatMap((dragStartEvent) => mousemove.pipe(
    takeUntil(mouseup))
  )
);

const dragend = mousedown.pipe(
  (dragEvent) => mouseup.pipe(first())
);

const log = (prefix: string) => (data: MouseEvent) => console.log(`${prefix}: x: ${data.clientX}, y:${data.clientY}`);

dragstart.subscribe(log('dragstart'));
dragmove.subscribe(log('dragmove'));
dragend.subscribe(log('dragend'));
```

The problem is that operators `takeUntil` and `first` mark the stream as completed.
This means that `dragstart` and `dragend` will only fire once. Is there a way to somehow reset the stream after this event happens?
For example by resetting the `dragstart` stream when the `mouseup` stream receives an event.

---

### Additional explanation

In the current implementation `dragstart` and `dragend` will be logged exactly once to the console after loading the page (& dragging). After that the stream is completed and no further events will be sent through it. I want to reset the stream every drag operation so the dragstart & dragend will work every drag operation rather than just the very first after loading the page.

#### Current behavior ([] represent mouse action that happened, *italic text* is console output):

**First drag operation**

- [mousedown]
- *dragstart*
- [mousemove]
- *dragmove*
- [mouseup]
- *dragend*

**Second drag operation**

- [mousedown]
- (nothing happens, however dragstart should be logged to console)
- [mousemove]
- *dragmove*
- [mouseup]
- (nothing happens, however dragend should be logged to console)

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for working example
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMWjEV[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMWjEV)

```js
const { fromEvent } = Rx.Observable;
const target = document.querySelector('.box');

const mouseup = fromEvent(target, 'mouseup');
const mousemove = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
const mousedown = fromEvent(target, 'mousedown');
let log = (prefix: string, x:number, y:number) => console.log(`${prefix}: x: ${x}, y:${y}`);
const mousedrag = mousedown.selectMany((md) => {

  const startX = md.clientX + window.scrollX,
        startY = md.clientY + window.scrollY,
        startLeft = parseInt(md.target.style.left, 10) || 0,
        startTop = parseInt(md.target.style.top, 10) || 0;
  
  return mousemove.map((mm) => {
    mm.preventDefault();
   log('mousemove',mm.clientX, mm.clientY);
    return {
      left: startLeft + mm.clientX - startX,
      top: startTop + mm.clientY - startY
    };
  }).takeUntil(mouseup);
});

subscription = mousedrag.subscribe((pos) => {
  log('dragstart',pos.top, pos.left)
  target.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
  target.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:solid 10px green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.2/rx.all.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not quite what I need. I've added some extra info to my question

Answer (score 0):

But you told to do so :)

If you remove the pipe and "first" operator from the dragstart stream

```
const dragstart = mousedown
```

the stream wont complete.
The dragmove wont complete anyway because it is mapped from the mousedown, not the dragstart stream

If you tell to the resulting stream to pick only the first one, the stream will complete after emitting once.

This code should work:

```
const mousedown = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'mousedown');
const mousemove = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'mousemove');
const mouseup = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'mouseup');

// I dont think it's necessary to duplicate
const dragstart = mousedown

// No need to map to something else
const dragend = mouseup

const dragmove = dragstart.pipe(
  concatMapTo( 
    mousemove.pipe(
        takeUntil( dragend )
    )
  )
);



const log = (prefix: string) => (data: MouseEvent) => console.log(`${prefix}: x: ${data.clientX}, y:${data.clientY}`);

dragstart.subscribe(log('dragstart'));
dragmove.subscribe(log('dragmove'));
dragend.subscribe(log('dragend'));
```